# child component doesn't update when I update input variable - Angular

Tags: angular, render, updates

I have child component and in this I pass as input an value from parent component. In parent component I'm updating this input variable on event emmiter trigger, but the child component doesn't update. I've checked in augury the input variable updates. Why child component don't updates?

ParentComponent.html

```
<app-child
[data]="data"
(filterEmmiter)="filter($event)">
</app-child>
```

ParentComponent.ts

```
data: any;
.
.
.
getUsers() {
  this.usersService.getAllUsers().subscribe(res => {
    this.data = res;
  });
}
.
.
.

filter(data){
  this.data = data
}
```

Comment: Can you show you `app-child` component. It's fairly important here...

Comment: KurtHamilton isn't any important thing here, just i'm getting data variable as @Input and iterating in html file

Comment: What style of change detection are you using?  Does the OnChanges lifecycle event fire in ```app-child```?

Comment: @night_owl i'm not using any type of change detection, which one I need to use?

Comment: The default change detection should be fine.  There are some caveats to remember if using OnPush, but you're not, so no worries there!

Comment: Just to clarify, you are saying that when `data` change value in the parent the child is not updating?.

Comment: @hxhzre Of course it's important to see the child component - that's what's failing to update here. Everyone's here trying to guess your problem, and you're hiding crucial information

Comment: @cabesuon yes exactly

Comment: @KurtHamilton sorry I forgot to say, in child component i'm using another component and this data what comes from parent component i'm passing to child component inside the child component.

Comment: @hxhzre **Anything** that is important should be in the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can try like this, here you want to get the data from the parent component to child component, Here your parent component is `ParentComponent` and child component is `app-child` so here for getting the data from parent to child we can use `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)`

**ParentComponent.html**

```
<app-child
[data]="data"
(filterEmmiter)="filter($event)">
</app-child>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, Input} from '@angular/core';

class Child  implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input() Data: any; // here is the data variable which we are getting from the parent 

    constructor() {}

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
      console.log(changes); // here you will get the data from parent once the input param is change
    }   

}
```

Comment: ngOnchanges here i update Data with currentData, but html not renders again

Comment: did you mean you rename the data variable with currentd ? if yes then you have to rename `@Input data: any`  with the `@Input currentd: any`.

Comment: i've made like this `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    this.data = changes.data.currentValue;
  }`

Comment: yeah perfect !!

Comment: no, and before making this i was checking with one extension what shows current state of all app, the variable is updated in everywhere, but this changes doesn't effect to html.

Comment: @hxhzre why aren't you posting your child component code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was also facing something similar, in my case, using the Onchanges method in the child, I saw that the input change happens after the logic that I want to execute then the a new value of the input doesn't get reflected in this logic.

What I did was to force the detect changes in the place I assigned the input data like this:

I add this to my constructor

```
 constructor( private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

Then where I assigned a value to the data

```
this.data=something
this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
```

After that, I notice that the method onChanges was called first and then the logic with the new value of the input, After that I just set manually the value of the input in the Onchanges method that should be placed in the child component

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.put= changes.input.currentValue;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that you need to take whatever code you have in ngOnInit() and put it in ngOnChanges()

If you have code that looks like formBuilder.group( ....) , this needs to go in ngOnChanges().

ngOnInit fires once. So doing it wrong will work the first time.

ngOnChanges fires every time an @Input changes (paraphrasing the doc...). So when you click on nav elements, and show the new Item, the child object will respond as expected.

**You must import SimpleChanges from  @angular/core**

```
import { Component, OnInit, SimpleChanges ,Input, Output, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   
    //console.log('changes in child form',changes); // here you will get the data from parent once the input param is change
    this.udsFormGroup=   this.myFormGroupDefinition();
  
      this.udsFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe( data =>{
          this.formChanged();      
        });
  }
```

https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

here is a great article
https://www.stackchief.com/blog/ngOnChanges%20Example%20%7C%20Angular

Answer (score -1):

Your child components should expose an `EventEmitter`.

```
 @Output() filteremmiter = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Comment: This was created